# R: Need to perform multiple matches for each row in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where for each Filename value, there is a set of values for Compound. Some compounds have a value for IS.Name, which is a value that is one of the Compound values for a Filename.

```
,Batch,Index,Filename,Sample.Name,Compound,Chrom.1.Name,Chrom.1.RT,IS.Name,IS.RT
1,Batch1,1,Batch1-001,Sample001,Compound1,1,0.639883333,IS-1,0
2,Batch1,1,Batch1-001,Sample001,IS-1,IS1,0.61,NONE,0
```

For each set of rows with the same Filename value in my data frame, I want to match the IS.Name value with the corresponding Compound value, and put the Chrom.1.RT value from the matched row into the IS.RT cell. For example, in the table above I want to take the Chrom.1.RT value from row 2 for Compound=IS-1 and put it into IS.RT on row 1 like this:

```
,Batch,Index,Filename,Sample.Name,Compound,Chrom.1.Name,Chrom.1.RT,IS.Name,IS.RT
1,Batch1,1,Batch1-001,Sample001,Compound1,1,0.639883333,IS-1,0.61
2,Batch1,1,Batch1-001,Sample001,IS-1,IS1,0.61,NONE,0
```

If possible I need to do this in R. Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Here is a larger, more detailed example:

```
    Filename    Compound    Chrom.1.RT  IS.Name IS.RT
1   Sample-001  IS-1    1.32495 NONE    NA
2   Sample-001  Compound-1  1.344033333 IS-1    NA
3   Sample-001  IS-2    0.127416667 NONE    NA
4   Sample-001  Compound-2  0   IS-2    NA
5   Sample-002  IS-1    1.32495 NONE    NA
6   Sample-002  Compound-1  1.344033333 IS-1    NA
7   Sample-002  IS-2    0.127416667 NONE    NA
8   Sample-002  Compound-2  0   IS-2    NA
```

This is chromatography data. For each sample, four compounds are being analyzed, and each compound has a retention time value (Chrom.1.RT). Two of these compounds are references that are used by the other two compounds. For example, compound-1 is using IS-1, while IS-1 does not have a reference (IS). Within each sample I am trying to match up the IS Name to the compound row for it to grab the CHrom.1.RT and put it in the IS.RT field. So for Compound-1, I want to find the Chrom.1.RT value for the Compound with the same name as the IS.Name field (IS-1) and put it in the IS.RT field for Compound-1. The tables I'm working with list all of the compounds together and don't match up the values for the references, which I need to do for the next step of calculating the difference between Chrom.1.RT and IS.RT for each compound. Does that help?

EDIT - Here's the code I found that seems to work:

```
sampleList<- unique(df1$Filename)
for (i in sampleList){
   SampleRows<-which(df1$Filename == sampleList[i])
   RefRows <- subset(df1, Filename== sampleList[i])
   df1$IS.RT[SampleRows]<- RefRows$Chrom.1.RT[ match(df1$IS.Name[SampleRows], RefRows$Compound)] 
    }
```

I'm definitely open to any suggestions to make this more efficient though.

Comment: Thank you akrun for the formatting help!

Comment: Try `df1$IS.RT <- with(df1, Chrom.1.RT[match(IS.Name, Compound)])` and replace the `NA` with 0

Comment: For the ones with a value in IS.Name that matched with a Compound, it put in 0 for the IS.RT rather than grabbing the Chrom.1.RT value correctly. I had a similar result using df1$IS.RT<- df1$Chrom.1.RT[ match(df1$IS.Name, df1$Compound)].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest in the future you provide your example as the output of dput(df1) as it makes it a lot easier to read it into R instead of the space delimited table you provided

That being said, I've managed to wrangle it into R with the "help" of MS Excel.

```
df1=structure(list(Filename = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Sample-001", "Sample-002"), class = "factor"), 
Compound = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Compound-1", 
"Compound-2", "IS-1", "IS-2"), class = "factor"), Chrom.1.RT = c(1.32495, 
1.344033333, 0.127416667, 0, 1.32495, 1.344033333, 0.127416667, 
0), IS.Name = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("IS-1", 
"IS-2", "NONE"), class = "factor"), IS.RT = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Filename", "Compound", 
"Chrom.1.RT", "IS.Name", "IS.RT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

The code below is severely clunky but it does the job.

```
library("dplyr")
df1=tbl_df(df1)
left_join(df1,left_join(df1%>%select(-Compound),df1%>%group_by(Compound)%>%summarise(unique(Chrom.1.RT)),c("IS.Name"="Compound")))%>%select(-IS.RT)%>%rename(IS.RT=`unique(Chrom.1.RT)`)
```

Unless I got i wrong, this is what you need?

Comment: Added some more detail in a better example, and a proposed code solution. Thanks for the suggestion!